# Instantiating class of type parameter within generic class

Tags: typescript

Why is the following not possible in TypeScript?

```
class C<T> {
    make(): T {
      return new T()
    }
}
let a = new C<Array>().make()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's "not possible" because at runtime, types are erased. Therefore there is no `T`.

However in other languages this is possible.